A semi-algebraic set in $\mathbb{R}^d$ has dimension $d$ if and only if its interior is non empty
I would like to prove the following result :

A semi-algebraic set in $\mathbb{R}^d$  has dimension $d$ if and only if its interior is non empty

The dimension here has to be understood in the semi algebraic sense as defined now :

A semi-algebraic set $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ can always be decomposed as $A=\cup_{k=1}^{n}A_k$ where the $A_k$’s are disjoint semi algebraic sets such that each of them is semi algebraically homeomorphic to $(0,1)^{d_k}$. The dimension of $A$ is then defined to be $\dim(A)=\max_{1\leq k\leq p}\{d_k\}$.

Here is my attempt :
Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ be semi-algebraic.
Suppose it’s dimension is $d$ but it’s interior is empty.
We now by the decomposition of semi algebraic set in $\mathbb{R}^d$ that
$$
A =\cup_{k=1}^{p}A_k
$$
Where the $A_k$’s are disjoint semi algebraic sets such that each of them is semi algebraically homeomorphic to $(0,1)^{d_k}$.
Moreover $\dim(A)=\max_{1\leq k\leq p}\{d_k\}=d$ by assumption.
Take the $A_k$ that is semi algebraically isomorphic to $(0,1)^d$. Observe that $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4})^d$ is a proper subset of $(0,1)^d$. Now take the semi algebraic homeomorphism $h:A_k\to (0,1)^d$.
We know that $h^{-1}((\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4})^d)$ is open in $A_k$, this means it is of the form
$$
h^{-1}((\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4})^d) = U\cap A_k
$$
But $A$ has empty interior, this implies that $U\cap A_k$ is either empty or the set $A_k$, both contradicting the fact that $h$ is a bijection. We conclude that $A_k$ is not homeomorphic to $(0,1)^d$. We can repeat this argument to all the $A_k$’s homeomorphic to $(0,1)^d$, which contradicts the fact that $\dim A=d$.
For the reverse implication, let’s try by contradiction. Assume that $\mathring{A}\neq\emptyset$ but $\dim(A)\neq d$. First $\dim(A)<d$. Moreover $\mathring{A}$ is a nonempty open semi-algebraic set so   $\dim(\mathring{A})=d$ by a well know property on non empty open semi-algebraic set of $\mathbb{R}^d$.Since $\mathring{A}\subset A$ we have $\dim(A)\geq\dim(\mathring{A})=d$ which is a contradiction.
For the reverse implication, the fact that $\dim(A)<d$ seems to be a shortcut, I should justify it properly I think !
If you have some remarks/hints do not hesitate please
Thank you a lot

About the fact that $\dim(A)<d$ :
We can justify this by the fact that $A\subset\mathbb{R}^d\implies\dim(A)\leq\dim(\mathbb{R}^d)=d$

You have to start by defining the notion of dimension, "semialgebraic sense," is unclear.

@MoisheKohan Thank you for your comment and sorry for this ambiguity,  I updated the post !

Is it clear that such a finite decomposition exists? I know of existence of countable decompositions. Where did you find this definition of semialgebraic dimension?

You can find it in the book "Real algebraic geometry" by Coste and al.  it is the theorem $2.3.6$ page $33$ and this definition of the semi-algebraic dimension is a consequence of this decomposition theorem, they proved that such definition coincides with a more intrinsec one defined as the Krull dimension of $\mathbb{R}[x]/ I(A)$ where $I(A)$ is the ideal of polynomials vanishing on $A$

OK, then it is a consequence invariance of dimension theorem for homeomorphisms (which is easier if you assume smoothness or that homeomorphism is semalgebraic).

@MoisheKohan Thank you !  I did not think to this result, it is not totally clear how to make this but starting by assuming that there exists $d'>d$ such that one $A_k$ is homeomorphic to $(0,1)^{d'}$ , the composition with a good homeomorphism should give the homeomorphism between two open set if $\mathbb{R}^{d'}$ and $\mathbb{R}^d$ hence the contradiction.. I will try this !

You can use the cell decomposition Theorem (you already used it for the decomposition that you mentioned). I will recall it (you can find it in any book of semialgebraic, subanalytic or o-minimal geometry).
For a given positive integer $p$ (we need only $p=0$ in your situation), a semialgebraic set $C$ in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ is referred to as a $C^{p}$-cell if:
case $d=1$: $C$ is either a point or an open interval.
case $d\geq 2$: $C$ is one of the following:
$\bullet$ $C=\Gamma_{\phi}$ (the graph of $\phi$), where $\phi:B\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a $C^{p}$ semialgebraic function, and $B$ is a $C^{p}$-cell in $\mathbb{R}^{d-1}$.
$\bullet$ $C=\Gamma(\phi , \varphi)=\{ (x,y) \in B\times \mathbb{R} \; : \; \phi(x)<y<\varphi(x)  \}$, where $\phi$ and $\varphi$ are two $C^{p}$ semialgebraic functions on a $C^{p}$-cell $B$, satisfying $\phi < \varphi$ with the possibility of $\phi=-\infty$ or $\varphi =+\infty$.
A $C^{p}$-cell decomposition of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ is defined by induction as follows:
$\bullet$ A $C^{p}$-cell decomposition of $\mathbb{R}$ is a finite partition consisting of points and open intervals.
$\bullet$ A $C^{p}$-cell decomposition of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ is a finite partition $\mathcal{P}$ of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ by $C^{p}$-cells. It is required that $\pi(\mathcal{P})$ is a $C^{p}$-cell decomposition of $\mathbb{R}^{d-1}$, where $\pi: \mathbb{R}^{d}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{d-1}$ is the standard projection, and $\pi(\mathcal{P})$ is the family:
$\pi(\mathcal{P})=\{\pi(A) \; : \; A\in \mathcal{P} \}$.
Now you have the fundamental cell decomposition theorem:
Theorem: Let $p\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\{ X_{1},...,X_{n} \}$ be a finite family of semialgebraic sets of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$. Then there is a $C^{p}$-cell decomposition of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ compatible with this family, i.e. each $X_{i}$ is a union of some cells.
Take $A$ a semialgebraic subset of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ a cell decomposition of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ compatible with $A$, then we define the dimension (as you did)
$dim_{\mathcal{C}}(A)=max\{ dim(C) \; : \; C\subset A \; and \; C\in \mathcal{C} \}$.
This number does not depend on $\mathcal{C}$ (easy exercice that follows from the cell decomposition theorem), we denote it by $dim(A)$. Note that this is also the Hausdorff dimension of $A$.
Now your statement is equivalent to the following:
"A cell $C\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is of dimension $d$ if and only if it is open"
You can use The invariance of dimension theorem or you can avoid it and use the Induction definition of the cell (the dimension of $C$ will be the same as dimension of $\pi (C)$ if it is a graph or dimension of $\pi (C) +1 $  in the other case).
